# Change stack space

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-construction

Currently, I trying to implement shared stack in cluster system. This system has two address spaces, one private and shared between all processor.

How could I change the beginning and ending of the stack in c programming?

Namely, I want to put stack in a shared space and change the flow of program to use it.

Comment: What do you need that for? Want all threads to use same stack? there's no way that's ever gonna work. Want to pass pointers to stuff on one stack to another thread? bad idea, the synchronization implications would kill you. Want to have a shared stack where any thread can push/pop things, now that's a different story. So please elaborate on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: My idea using a shared stack for communication between threads by passing the pointers. The idea is, sending the pointer of shared variable to other processor by message. Then processor could access to this shared address without need to copy the data to its space.

Comment: In addition, I don"t want using the malloc or other form to allocate data and passing its pointer. I need to do procedure same as OpenMP model.

Comment: Your idea is shared memory; why does it have to be shared stack?  If it *just* shared memory and not shared stack, you don't need threads to change stacks and your problem goes away.

Comment: ...  I think you will find that if you have undifferentiated shared memory between all processes, that you are likely to have a bad time making sure that memory is available to all the threads with low latency and good coherency (others hint at this by talking about synchronization).

Comment: @Ira Baxter, yes it is a physical shared memory between all processors. To sharing the data between all participant, I need to allocated the data and passing it offset to others and so on. In my implementation, I want to give this task to compiler, How?. When the compiler finds some note (e.g., shared var;) from programmer, it will do the previous procedure.

Comment: In a comment to another answer, you say "(My) platform is similar to a DSM", to my decoding == Distributed Shared Memory.  This contradicts what you just said about "physical shared memory". Which is it? I don't think you have communicated your architecture to us readers very well.  You'll get correspondingly inappropriate answers.

Comment: I said, it is similar to a DSM (distributed shared memory). The common point between my platform and DSM is shared memory excited. Otherwise,  you can not access to shared variable direct without using a way to sort the address. However, my system has multicore and each one has own OS and using the message or socket to communication. It has also a small memory is visible to all cores. So, in my work, I want to avoid the overhead of exchange the information by message by exploiting this small area. I know it, I need to synchronization operation and consistent view for this area.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is: stay away from passing pointers to stack based objects at all cost. If you did this, you would require the sending thread to never return from the function that created the shared object before it can *proove* that no other thread is going to access that object in any way anymore. This is a) next to impossible, and b) would require performance killing locking. The consequences of failure to do this correctly would be entirely undeterministic bugs! Do not do this!

I would advice to malloc *all* objects that are to leave the context of one thread and use thread safe reference counting on them. You might also take a look at thread safe shared data structures like queues, double linked lists, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, a several implementation of OpenMP has been ported on cluster or DSM system. My platform is similar to DSM. I trying to implement a new programming model that supports shared memory application on cluster. Therefore, I need to implement shared stack like the idea in section 4.6 from this paper: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-68555-5_7#page-1

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can achieve what you want nicely in C (unless you want to change the compiler).

You say you want an OpenMP style of programming. That is tantamount to a single top level thread, that can fork children to operate on shared space provided by the parent.  Fancy OpenMP does this recursively.

To do this *nicely*, you system/tools/compiler need to be able to identify

```
*   threads of computations  
*   what variables are declared by each thread
*   what variables (or parts thereof) are offered by a thread to its thread children
```

If you can do these things (and it is easier with explicit language support, OpenMP enabled compilers are aided in this process by the OpenMP pragmas), then you can partition a thread's data into 3 parts:

```
1.  storage accessed only by the thread, and not by its children
2.  storage declared by the thread, but accessed only by individual children (e.g., slices of arrays)
3.  storage read and written by the parent thread and its children
```

At this point, you can consider layout out "local variables" for a thread, and thus to stack space.
Thread-local storage is allocated *only* to the parent thread's stack space.  Parent-declared but child-processed storage becomes space allocated to the child's local space/stacks.  Storage read and written by all, can be placed anywhere it can be accessed (in the parent thread's local space, in his stack, in heap store) and will need access protection to prevent data races.  [You can't coerce traditional C compilers to do this for you.]

This partitioning of the data to different thread local/stack spaces makes your apparent scheme of using C and setting "all threads stacks" to *one* place in shared memory difficult to harness.  If all threads have the same stack area, which storage is local to a thread?  In particular, if two threads each want to write to their own local variable I, and I is in the shared space, then it isn't really local.  If you partition the shared space into disjoint thread stacks, then you don't really have sharing of storage, at least not by name; at best you can share using pointers into other threads stacks.   All this will be difficult to program, therefore error prone and I wouldn't want to have to debug programs written for such a system.  It also places additional demand on your precious shared space; you have thread-local variables eating it up, but not needing sharing.

If you have a static number of threads, and continue to insist on using some available C compiler, you might be better off to hand-allocate the shared data (either dynamically at runtime, or at coding/compile-time by partitioning the shared memory).  But your threads can now run with their "standard" stack in their local memories and no stack switching is needed.

[EDIT:  After my comment on cactus stacks, OP wanted to know more. I' m including
the comment here, and some pointers to details about them]

A stack can be shared by multiple threads. The notion of a *cactus stack* is one in which a parent thread, having an existing (cactus) stack, shares that with all of its parallel children, who each get stack space of their own but can see/share the parent's stack.

Our PARLANSE parallel programming language implements this concept directly, and we use it in application programs that are some 2-4 million lines of code.  Each function call heap-allocates
its activation records (using a thread local allocator for speed), and has access to all parent stack segments by lexical-level up addressing, implemented as a box of pointers passed by a parent to its child on a function call.   The Intel blog below describes exactly the reasons we did this.

References:

- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_stack
- Intel http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/the-thorny-problem-of-the-cactus-stack
- VM for cactus stack: http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~sbw/papers/pact183a-lee.pdf
- PARLANSE: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/PARLANSE

Comment: In the OpenMP model original, the stack of master thread is shared between all threads. So, the gcc compiler collects all the pointer of those local/global variable and put them in the meta data (structure) and passing to other threads as argument. Then, compiler exchanges all the references of the variable to pointer (e.g, int a ---> int *a). In the end, all threads could access them by using pointer.

Comment: In my implementation, I need to make the stack of master processor visible to all other processor by allocating it in a known address space and then by remapping the address space of each slave processor by same virtual address of Master core. In the end, every processor could access to those variable by using the original mechanism of gcc compiler. So, it will not need to change the original implementation of OpenMP approach.

Comment: Regarding GCC's OpenMP scheme: the phrase "stack of the master thread is shared" is easily misinterpreted. What you describe makes sense, but the master thread stack isn't shared in the sense that all threads *set their stack pointer* to the master stack location or event anywhere inside it; rather, each thread, as you describe, has its own stack, and a box of pointers to interesting places in the master stack is passed to the children.  So 1) it doesn't resemble what your question is to be asking to do, and 2) it requires the help of the GCC compiler to do it.  Can you modify your compiler?

Comment: If you can modify your compiler, I suggest a master thread whose space is NOT in your shared space.  Instead, an ideal solution is to lift all the shared variables out of the master's stack, and allocate them to the shared memory area.  Pass the box of pointers to the *master* and all the children, or pass them all a shared virtual address page.

Comment: ... you are proposing the use GCC unchanged?  Huh.  Well, I might be convinced this would work. Yes, you'd need to set each thread's stack pointer, but you'd be setting them to different places.  Its easy enough. For the main thread, literally in main you drop into assembler, save the existing ESP into some main program StackSave, load ESP with the location of your shared memory (and reverse this when exiting main). I'm not sure what you do with the OpenMP child threads, because they are launched by some custom code generated by the GCC compiler, that you'd need to intercept and modify.

Answer (score -1):

Let me edit a little bit for clarity:

You are just trying to change the meaning and definition of STACK. STACK by Today's definition can be used only by one thread for real STACK operations. The STACK can be shared by processes or threads for using like ordinary memory. In this case, You are really supposed to call that chunk of memory as "Shared Memory" not as a "Shared Stack". What are you really trying to do or achieve in the cluster environment?

Here is an example why STACK cannot be shared...

Thread-1 function call sequence:

```
main()
    thr1_f1()
        thr1_f2()
            thr1_f3()
    thr1_f4()
```

Thread-2 function call sequence:

```
main()
    thr2_f1()
        thr2_f2()
            thr2_f3()
    thr2_f4()
```

Assume that these threads are sharing STACK. Here is a possible function call sequence...

1. Thread-1 is in the middle of thr1_f1() and goes to sleep in processor core-1.
2. Thread-2 starts and in the middle of thr2_f2() and goes to sleep in processor core-2.
3. Thread-1 comes up and calls thr1_f2(). This will overwrites Thread-2 STACK area. Local variables and parameters of thr2_f2() are messed up now.
4. Thread-2 will not be able to run and/or get it's return address in thr2_f1(). Depending on timing, it may get some address and dump the core.

Comment: any reference for that definition of a stack?

Comment: A stack *can* be shared by multiple threads.  The notion of a cactus stack in one in which a parent thread, having an existing (cactus) stack, shares that with all of its parallel children, who each get stack space of their own but can see/share the parent's stack.  Our PARLANSE parallel programming language implements this concept directly, and we use it application programs that are some 2-4 million lines of code. See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/PARLANSE

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Could you give us more details about a cactus stack schema? Also, it is possible to implement it in Linux? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can implement this anywhere you want if you have enough control of the compiler.  That comes with a price: you have take control of the compiler, and that's usually a very big project.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: As you said each thread gets it's own stack and each thread will only use it's own stack for push and pop operations. This is what I really meant. One thread can see only one chunk of Memory as STACK and use that for function calling and return. one child thread seeing parent thread's stack doesn't mean it can use that as STACK (no push and pop on parent thread's STACK). It can only use that as any other memory locations and use it that way...

Comment: @qdii: STACK is LIFO Data Structure and should be used only in that way to keep standards and definitions. [Reference to Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29)

Comment: @SukumarSwaminathan you wrote "STACK by Today's definition can be used only by one thread", but this is misleading since this property is not part of the **definition** of a stack (which has no notion of threads). A LIFO structure could well be shared by many threads, if properly synchronized: actually, this is the case when a stack is used as the shared container of a producer/consumer pattern.